# Using a C++ future as an intermediate value in a function stack results in a segfault

Tags: c++, c++11, promise, future

I'm having some trouble understanding C++11 promises, futures, and how they interact with different contexts.

Overall, my goal is to have a program that generates values in a compute thread and prints them in the main thread. Before the main thread gets the generated value, I want to intercept and change it. In the example code at the bottom, a future with value `asdf` is intercepted and `redirect:` is prepended, returning `redirect:asdf` to the future.

Compiling this code with LLVM 9, GCC 5/6/7, or Visual C++ 19 works fine. However, all blow up on `f.get()` in the lambda while throwing strange errors. For example, debugging using LLVM (LLDB) on MacOS gives `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18)` from somewhere deep in the futures library, then croaks with exit code 11 (segfault). I do not think it is a problem with the library implementation because it behaves the same on all compilers.

There are a couple ways I've found to make the error go away, but then the code isn't in the structure I want. One is to simply `return f;` from `push_redirect`, discarding the async stuff and not changing the future's value. The other is to call `push_new` from `main` instead of `push_redirect`, also not changing the future's value. At the end of the day, I'd like to be able to stack as many of the future redirections as I want.

Is there anything I'm doing that's particularly wrong? I suspect it might have something to do with the capture-by-reference of the lambda, but I don't know how to arrange the code to avoid the capture-by-reference without using global variables. It could also be something to do with scope.

Below is a minimal example, stripped down from the larger program that is exhibiting this bug. It should compile on any [online](http://rextester.com/EWGL67236) or offline C++ compiler that can handle C++11 or better.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <queue>

struct PromiseContainer {
    std::promise<std::string> p;
};

std::queue<PromiseContainer *> q;

void other_thread()
{
    std::string str("abcd");

    while (true) {
        while (q.empty());

        auto pc = q.front();
        q.pop();

        if (pc == nullptr) break;
        else {
            pc->p.set_value(str);
            delete pc;
        }
    }
}

std::future<std::string> push_new()
{
    auto p = std::promise<std::string>();
    auto f = p.get_future();

    auto pc = new PromiseContainer();
    pc->p = std::move(p);
    q.push(pc);

    return f;
}

std::future<std::string> push_redirect()
{
    auto f = push_new();
    return std::async(std::launch::deferred, [&]()->std::string {
        return "redirect:" + f.get();
    });
}

int main()
{
    auto t = std::thread(other_thread);

    auto f = push_redirect();
    q.push((PromiseContainer *) nullptr);

    f.wait();
    std::cout << f.get() << std::endl;

    t.join();
}
```

Comment: You have a race condition on your queue. You can't read to and write from it from two different threads without some kind of synchronization. Also why the `PromiseContainer`?

Comment: Yeah, I should have probably explained that better. The queue is actually fine-ish in this example. The code that I pulled this from does use access synchronization. I omitted it from the above code to focus on the main issue (which turned out to be a scope problem in `push_redirect`). The trivial `PromiseContainer` exists because I wanted to structure my demo code like the code I started from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f` in `push_redirect` is local variable so your lambda (with &)

```
[&]()->std::string {
    return "redirect:" + f.get();
});
```

holds reference to this variable, when `push_redirect` ends `f` is deleted and you get undefined behaviour - thread created by async wants to read data which was destroyed.

If you are using C++14 you can move `f` future object in capture list of lambda:

```
std::future<std::string> push_redirect()
{
  auto f = push_new();
  return std::async(std::launch::deferred, [f = std::move(f)]() mutable ->std::string {
    return "redirect:" + f.get();
  });
}
```

You should also use mutex to synchronize access to your `q` queue.

Comment: C++14 is acceptable, and you did solve my problem. Thanks for the explanation. I wasn't aware you could `move` futures right in the captures list. Is there any documentation that talks about it?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda in section *lambda capture*, there are examples with capture initializer.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. Thanks. Also about the synchronization you mention, the code I started from uses a mutex and condition variable instead of a busy-wait loop. I omitted it in the code I posted to focus on the scope bug.